# How to delete lines that match a pattern

Tags: design-patterns, awk

I have a script that delete all lines in a given file that has two patterns present, **nameX** and **surnameX** for example. The problem is that sometime in other fields further in the line the nameX can appear and it deletes the line also

**nameX** **surnameX** sdkflfjffsl sdlfjsd flsdkjsdjf sdlfdf > ok to delete

**nameY** **surnameY** ddsfdsfsfsf sf sdfdfdfdsfdsf fdf fsdf > keep line

**nameY** **surnameX** dfdsfsffsfsdf fsfsdfsff **nameX** fdsfffs > deletes, but i dont wat it to. How to proceed ?

My code is below

```
awk '$0!~v1 || $0!~v2' v1="nameX" v2="surnameX" /home/oldfile > /home/newfile
```

Help would be appreciatted :)

Comment: try `awk '$1!~v1 || $2!~v2' v1="nameX" v2="surnameX" /home/oldfile > /home/newfile`

Comment: $1 and $2 are the columns ?

Comment: yes, whereas `$0` is whole line

Comment: so, for instance if the vars nameX and surnameX are on the fourth and fifth colunms the code would be : $4 and $5, right ?

Comment: yes...................

Comment: thanks, going to give a try

Answer (score 0):

For the example you gave, you can just check the first fields in the input:

```
awk '!($1~v1 && $2~v2)' v1="nameX" v2="surnameX" /home/oldfile > /home/newfile
```

Note, here we are using regex matches, and if you know the exact value of the "pattern", a better way is using `==`(or `!=`), for example, `Tom` and `Tommy` are different names but both match `Tom`

```
awk '$1!=v1 || $2!=v2' v1="nameX" v2="surnameX" /home/oldfile > /home/newfile
```